# How can one say that an object is at rest when there is a constant acceleration $g$ acting on it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, free-body-diagram

A stationary object in a gravitational field, or a stationary charged particle in an electric field, has potential energy. If there is a constant acceleration, following this logic, how can I be at rest?

Answer (score 2):

It can be at rest, meaning not moving, if there is another force that is of equal magnitude and inverse direction to that generated by the potential energy of the fields.

Furthermore, if the particle is moving due to such a field it is possible (at least locally) to find another frame of reference where this particle is not moving.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing "velocity" and "acceleration".

An object is at rest if its velocity is 0. Of course it depends on the reference frame, but if you see it with $v=0$, then you see it at rest.

However, it doesn't mean it is in equilibrium. Acceleration is the rate of change of the velocity. The velocity CAN be 0 with non void acceleration. How? The key word is **instantly**.

In that case, the velocity is 0 but the acceleration is raising the speed, which means that it is 0 but it is going to be non zero in the very next instant. It lasts an infinitely small instant, but it exists.

The clearest example is when you throw something upwards. First the object goes upwards, everytime slower. Then it falls down. How can it change from going upwards to downwards? There MUST be a moment in which it stops. It stops for an infinitely small time, (literally infinitesimal). Then it starts moving down. That's your situation, $v=0$ but there's still acceleration on it.

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit to a previous answer: it is perfectly possible for an object to be subject to a constant acceleration yet have $0$ velocity at some instant.  The example of a ball near the surface of the Earth, experiencing a constant acceleration $-g$, is illustrative.
If you throw the ball up, with some initial velocity $v_0$, it will slow down, reach a maximum height $h_0$ and then start coming down again.  At the top of the trajectory, when the ball reaches $h_0$, its velocity is instantaneously $0$ for if it were not it would continue up.

Mathematically, the velocity as a function of time is given by
$$
v(t)=v_0-gt  \tag{1}
$$
since, by definition, the acceleration is just $dv/dt=-g$ and is indeed constant, and $v(0)=v_0$.
It is clear from (1) there is $t_0$ such that $v(t_0)=0$: this is just $t_0=v_0/g$.

Note that, in many problems, an object is *initially* at rest and may still be plunged in a field that will generate constant acceleration.  In such a case $v(0)=v_0=0$ at the start of the motion, but of course $v(t)\ne 0$ afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there are several mixed concepts in this question, but I will answer it because there is a language issue that I would like to discuss.

First of all, the existence of a potential does not imply there is acceleration, a ball in the bottom of a hole has still potential energy but it will not accelerate because its net force is zero.

The thing I would like to discuss is the definition of a particle "at rest". We say that a particle is at rest in relation to another or with a reference frame when its position does not change with time, that is when its relative velocity is zero.

If we observe an accelerating particle, there will be always an inertial reference frame A that is **instantaneously** at rest in relation to the particle, obviously, because the particle is accelerating, its velocity is continuously changing and therefore it is only at rest with that system for an instant.

That is how the definition of "at rest" works, but I think that saying that an accelerating particle is "at rest" is quite confusing, and I miss another word for saying that a particle has no net acceleration. Could we say "that particle is **calm**" in such a case?